# Drag and Drop (Dragger event) prevents onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, mouselistener

we have used one jquery library called as [jesse](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-Sorting-Of-Lists-jesse.html) which works fine

The thing is we have an **li** attributes and inside it we have used onclick event .. but somehow it stops working and we are unable to call onclick event .. Here is the fiddle for better understanding

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-Sorting-Of-Lists-jesse/jquery-jesse.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  
$(function(){
  
  // removing image onclick close button 
  $("#list").on("click", ".close_product", function (event) {
    console.log('inside onclick function');
    });
  
  $('#list').jesse({
   onStop: function(position, prevPosition, item) {
    console.log('inside list function');
    if(position == 0){
     item.addClass("drop-high").removeClass("drop-small");;
     $( "#list" ).find( "li:nth-child(2)" ).removeClass("drop-high").addClass("drop-small");
    }
    if(prevPosition == 0){
      item.addClass("drop-small").removeClass("drop-high");
     $( "#list" ).find( "li:nth-child(1)" ).removeClass("drop-small").addClass("drop-high");
    
    }
   },
  });
 });
  </script> 
 <ul class="jq-jesse" id="list">
                                  <li class="drop-high"><div class="high"><div class="close close_product">X</div><img src="https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1459870313PHP-logo.svg.png" width="20%"></div> </li>
                                  <li class="drop-small"><div class="high"><div class="close close_product">X</div><img src="https://phpwomen.org/holdingpage/images/usergroups/phpne.png" width="20%"></div> </li>
                                  <li class="drop-small"><div class="high"><div class="close close_product">X</div><img src="http://d3gnp09177mxuh.cloudfront.net/tech-page-images/php.png" width="20%"></div></li>
                                  <li class="drop-small"><div class="high"><div class="close close_product">X</div><img src="http://unitedwebsoft.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/advantage-of-php.jpg" width="20%"></div></li>
                                
                                </ul>
```

As you can see above, i have `onclick` function, but its not working. How can i make it work ?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @Novice see console log .. onclick event is not working ..

Comment: can you add a fiddle so that it's easier for us to test and apply changes

Comment: @FllnAngl above is the fiddle only dear.

Comment: oh my bad, I overlooked that. haha

Comment: @FllnAngl its alright dear .. you can read the solution below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library doesn't use drag events. It listens to `mousedown` and if fired it stops default execution with `e.preventDefault();` and watches over `$(document).on('mousemove')` and `.on('mouseup')`.

Therefore closing `div` can't hear any `click` event. You can slightly modify the library file to make it identify closing clicks.

1. Add specific setting, say, `closingClass` to the class (line 7)

   ```
   var settings = $.extend({
       closingClass: 'closing', 
       selector:    'li',
       dragClass:   '_isDragged',
       placeholder: '<li class="jq-jesse__placeholder"></li>'
   }, options);
   ```
2. Change listening of clicks at closing divs by adding the following 3 lines:

   ```
   list.on('mousedown', settings.selector, function(e){
       if($(e.target).hasClass(settings.closingClass)) {
           return true;
       }
   ```
3. That's it. Now you can't drag using a div having `closingClass`. You can add their own listeners.

Fiddle [with fixed library code](https://jsfiddle.net/ktxzh3gd/2/).

Comment: Superb!! Works well .. Thanks.